# Creating zero record parquet file using ab initio write HDFS component

Tags: ab-initio

There is a requirement where I have to create a zero record parquet file.
I have attached input table component to write HDFS component , and parquet file gets created properly when input table sql gives data.
However, when input table sql gives zero records , no file gets created. Expectation is that parquet file should get created but with zero records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into component property. Does it have option to create file?

Alternative way: use GDE component called "touch", it works exactly as similar Linux/Unix shell command/application